# ImageMagick convert -trim changing colors

Tags: imagemagick, blender

I'm creating sprites from 3d models in blender by rendering out the frames and then joining them together with ImageMagick. But when I run `convert image.png -trim image.png` on this one image the colours are being changed darker. How do I stop this or is it a bug?

#### Input File

[image: Correct Colors]

#### Output File

[image]

Comment: this is not normal behaviour. what version of imagemagick are you using?

Comment: The one in the ubuntu repo, Version: ImageMagick 6.7.7-10 2014-03-06 Q16

Comment: Works fine with Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-7 Q16 x86_64 2014-09-10

Comment: I followed [these](http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=24284#p105786) directions to build Version: ImageMagick 6.8.9-8 Q16 x86_64 2014-10-19. It still gives me the same results.

Comment: I had made a mistake the first time, I reinstalled it and now it's working!